# Ringing seen when charger is presented to DUT

Tags: power, battery-charging, power-electronics, inductive, ringing

The following is my setup:
[image]

Charger is set to 56V and 15A.
When charger is turned on there is significant ringing measured by the probe directly at the charger terminals. However this ringing is significantly diminished on the DUT side.

The cable connecting charger and DUT is a 2m long twisted cable.

I imagine the ringing is from inductive spiking? Why don't i see it on the DUT side? Is reducing the length of that cable all i can do to reduce it?

Here is my capture:
[image]

Comment: That's a typical underdamped circuit, You can increase the damping, but that will decrease your rise time.

Comment: But why don't i see the ringing on the load side? It's the same cable just measured 2m apart.

Comment: Is this just caused by reflection? Owing to the length of the cable?

Comment: What is the frequency of the ringing?

Comment: If it was reflection you'd see much more at the DUT end. What are these devices exactly and what is the spec of the cable?

Comment: @Hasman404 Probably not. The ringing has a period of around 5 µs, in that time light travels 1.5 km which is nowhere near the 2 m cable length.

Comment: @Finbarr the DUT is basically a battery which would be connected to some motor controllers (who's input capacitances would be charged at the time this test was conducted).

Comment: Spec of cable is generic 10AWG PVC cable. I am not sure about it's absolute specifics.

Comment: @Klas-Kenny why do we not see the ringing on the battery side?

Comment: @Hasman404 The battery probably "absorbs" the ringing (a battery can in this case be seen as a large capacitor), but due to inductance in the cable the same effect does not fully occur on the other side.

Comment: Are you happy that your oscilloscope probe earths will be bypassing the cable and possibly conducting an unhealthy amount of the charging current? Are your probes identical and set-up/trimmed correctly?

Comment: The probes are identical and trimmed. Ah i see i could have damaged the probes as there are 2 return paths in the image above. How would it be probed correctly? Could this have any impact on the ringing observed?

Comment: Sorry, the oscilloscope scales are hard to read and I didn't realize they were in your image.

Comment: Is the charger designed to deal with that high of frequency.  At that frequency electrolytic capacitors usually act like inductors.

Comment: Ideally for 200 kHz, both terminals of the battery and charger would look like ground.  Of course as you increase the frequency, nothing looks like ground.  Here, you're dealing with what isn't ideal about the charger.  The battery appears to better fit the ideal.

Comment: If the ringing will interfere with circuitry tied to the battery, you can use a resistor in series, whose value is determined by this https://www.intmath.com/differential-equations/8-2nd-order-de-damping-rlc.php.  If you are only charging a battery, the ringing probably doesn't matter.

Comment: My suspicion is the capacitance of the battery is much higher than the charge circuitry, and the inductance of the cable between them is kicking back onto the charger.

Comment: It doesn't seem to cause any issues so i won't change anything. Was more curious to understand why i didn't see ringing on the battery side.